# Autocomplete not working on dynamically generated form fields

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dynamic, autocomplete

I want to create a menu order form where users can dynamically enter which items they want by adding new fields to the form with the "Add Item" button. I also want the input fields to have autocomplete to help the user pick out the correct name for the item. Currently, I have the two features working independently as in the autocomplete works on the first default input field and I can add new fields but the new dynamically generated fields do not have the autocomplete and I am not sure why.

Autocomplete working on first input field:

[image: autocomplete working]

Adding new input fields working:

[image: new input fields]

Autocomplete NOT working on new input fields:

[image: not working on NEW fields]

I called my autocomplete function in the code where I am generating the new field and I am calling at specifically on the ID of the new field I generated but for some reason it still does not work.

Code for Autocomplete:

```
var items = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('items').textContent);
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
 /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
 the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
 var currentFocus;
 /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
     var a, b, i, val = this.value;
      /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
      closeAllLists();
  if (!val) { return false;}
  currentFocus = -1;
  /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
  a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
  /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
  this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
  /*for each item in the array...*/
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field 
value:*/
    if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
      /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
      b = document.createElement("DIV");
      /*make the matching letters bold:*/
      b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + " 
  </strong>";
      b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
      /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's 
   value:*/
      b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
      /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV 
  element):*/
          b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
          /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
          inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
          /*close the list of autocompleted values,
          (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
            closeAllLists();
        });
         a.appendChild(b);
      }
    }
   });
    /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
    inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
    if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
        if (e.keyCode == 40) {
          /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
          increase the currentFocus variable:*/
           currentFocus++;
           /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
           addActive(x);
   } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
     /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
     decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
     currentFocus--;
     /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
     addActive(x);
   } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
     /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being  
 submitted,*/
     e.preventDefault();
     if (currentFocus > -1) {
      /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
      if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
    }
  }
 });
 function addActive(x) {
     /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
     if (!x) return false;
    /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
       if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
        /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
       x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
 }
 function removeActive(x) {
    /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete 
items:*/
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
}
}

function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
      /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
     except the one passed as an argument:*/
     var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
     for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    } 
   }
  /*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
  document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  closeAllLists(e.target);
 });
 }
 autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput1"), items);
  /* Add rows to form dynamically */
```

Adding fields:

```
var counter = 1;
 $("#addrow").on("click", function () {
  if (counter < 20){
    counter++;
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";
    var optionList;
    for (var x = 1; x < 21; x++) {
        optionList += '<option value=' + x + '>' + x + '</option>';
    }
    cols += '<td><h3>' + counter + '.</h3></td>'
    cols += '<td><input type="search" id="myInput' + counter + '" 
    class="myInput form-control" placeholder = "Enter Item" 
    name="itemName' + counter + '" autocomplete="off"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><select class = "custom-select" name = "itemQuantity' + 
    counter + '">' + optionList +'</select></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-md btn- 
    danger "  value="Delete"></td>';

    newRow.append(cols);
    $("table.order-list").append(newRow);

    var element = document.getElementById("myInput"+counter);
    console.log(element);

    autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"+counter), items);

 }
 });

$("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
   $(this).closest("tr").remove();
counter -= 1 
});
```

Basically I want all my dynamically generated input fields to behave like my default input field.

Please feel free to ask me to clarify any aspect of my code or provide more of the code. Any help would be immensely appreciated, thank you.

Comment: thanks for the formatting help, @cloned

Comment: can you create an example where we can reproduce your problem? also , what's items here? `autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"+counter), items);`

Comment: items refers to a list of items such as ["Big Mac", "French Fries", "Soda"]. 

What do you mean by create an example where we can reproduce the problem btw?

Comment: I mean that you create a jsfiddle in your question with minimal HTML + JS so that we can reproduce your problem. We don't know what `items` really is . Or when these functions get called. And what happens before/after they are called.

Comment: Did you find the solution? @DesperateCoder